# Not able to understand Generic Methods

Tags: c#

I understand this statement  :-

`List<string> a;`

which means that a can contain values of only `string` type.

But when used with methods i get confused. For eg.

`public T1 methodName <T1,T2>(T1 t, T1 p)`

I understand the method is returning object of type `T1` and accepts objects of type T1. But what is the significance of `<T1,T2>`? Why is it required?

**Edit :-**
Based on the answers i received, i guess `<T1, T2>` are there so that input arguments looks similar. If `<T1>` was there then all input arguments must be of type T1 and if `<T1,T2>` is there means all arguments must be of type either `T1` or `T2`

But what exactly is meant by this statement :-

`public static TSummary Accumulate <TInput, TSummary> (IEnumerable <TInput> coll, Action <TInput, TSummary> action)`

The definition says all input must be of either `TInput` or `TSummary` but the second argument is of type `Action`. So i am still confused.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: "If <T1> was there then all input arguments must be of type T1 and if <T1,T2> is there means all arguments must be of type either T1 or T2" -- that statement is incorrect. The `<T1,T2>` does not mean T1 *or* T2, it just means the method is using two different types.

Comment: (You can read on MSDN about these). An Action represents a delegate that performs something with the parameters passed to it, without returning a result. All the types that are present there are input types, so you can say Action<T1,T2,T3> has 3 input parameters of type T1, T2, T3. A Func is a delegate that can take some parameters and returns a value, so the last type in the Func definition is the type of the return value: Func<T1,T2,T3> uses T1 and T2 internally and returns T3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the method is really defined in the way that you've typed *exactly*:

```
public T1 methodName <T1, T2>(T1 t, T1 p)
```

...then `T2` is unrelated to the argument types or return type. It might affect what's happening *inside the method*, however (e.g., the method may internally call `typeof(T2)` and do something with that).

If it was a typo, and the second parameter *should* read `T2 p`, then [DaeMoohn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649839/not-able-to-understand-generic-methods/3649856#3649856) is correct.

---

**UPDATE**:

> If `<T1>` was there then all input
>   arguments must be of type T1 and if
>   `<T1,T2>` is there means all arguments
>   must be of type either T1 or T2

**No! Inaccurate!**

The types of the parameters are specified right there in the parameter declaration: `(T1 t, T1 p)` -- both must be of type `T1` (just like if the parameters were declared `(int x, int y)` they'd both have to be `int`).

Let's look at that `Accumulate` signature:

```
public static TSummary Accumulate <TInput, TSummary> (IEnumerable <TInput> coll, Action <TInput, TSummary> action)
```

This method takes some sequence of `TInput` values (`coll`) and some delegate pointing to a method that accepts a `TInput` and a `TSummary` parameter (`action`). The method returns an object of type `TSummary`.

What's confusing about your *first* example is that one of the generic type arguments, `T2`, just happened not to be anywhere within the method signature itself. This simply means that `T2` is **not related to either the parameters or the return value**. But it could still be used within the method.

For example, consider this (fictional) method:

```
string GetTypeName<T>();
```

What does `T` mean in the above signature? It isn't the return type (`string`), nor is it in the parameter list (there are none). So does it mean anything? Presumably, it indicates what type you want to get the name of. So internally the method would probably look like this:

```
return typeof(T).FullName;
```

The point here is that `T2` in your first example must (if anything) affect only the **internals** of the method itself. Again: it is **not** related to the parameters or the return value.

Comment: @Dan : - `This method takes some sequence of TInput values (coll) and some delegate pointing to a method that accepts a TInput and a TSummary parameter (action). The method returns an object of type TSummary.` How did you know the method returns an object of type TSummary?

Comment: @Nitesh: Because that's the return type of the method: `public static TSummary Accumulate...`

Comment: Oh ok you're talking about `Accumulate`. I thought you were talking about `action`

Comment: @Nitesh: No, sorry, I can see that it wasn't so clear. But yeah, as I'm sure you know, an `Action<T1, T2>` has no return type.

Answer (score 2):

`public T1 methodName <T1,T2>(T1 t, T1 p)` lets you pass 2 generic parameters.
Hence, you can call this method in the following form

```
methodName<string, string>("hello", "world");
methodName<string, int>("hello", "world");
methodName<int, string>(1, 2);
```

Note: I didn't find the use of `T2` & don't know, why is it required when the method signature isn't using it. Hence, I am passing all the parameters above in string form.

Simply put, it means that the method accepts 2 parameters which can be any type of your choice (unless the restrictions are placed).

Comment: That last one isn't right. You could not pass "hello" and "world" to `methodName<int, string>` based on the signature provided by the OP (both arguments would have to be of type `int`).

Answer (score 1):

The `<T1,T2>` section is to tell the compiler that `T1` and `T2` are type parameters. Simply starting their names with "T" isn't enough, that's just a convention. Once you've defined the type parameter names, you can use the names wherever you would use a type inside the method and the method signature.

Comment: Thanks Douglas, for now i'll understand the fact they are just sort of namespace from where compiler detects the type ;) else it will give compilation error that T1 and T2 are not defined.

Answer (score 1):

> But what exactly is meant by this statement :-
>
> `public static TSummary Accumulate <TInput, TSummary>(IEnumerable <TInput> coll, Action<TInput, TSummary> action)`
>
> The definition says all input must be of either TInput or TSummary but the second argument is of type Action. So i am still confused.

The second argument is of type `Action<TInput, TSummary>`, not `Action`.

Answer (score 0):

It means methodName returns an object of type T1 and accepts two parameters of types T1 and T2.

Comment: But the way he's written it, the parameters are actually *both* of type `T1`.

Comment: Well... it accepts two type parameters, T1 and T2, and two parameters of type T1. Changing just T2 could change the behaviour of the method, even if all the normal parameters and the return value are T1, so it is valid. But it is unusual.

Comment: Well you are right, I didn't check the second parameter type!

Answer (score 0):

In order to define the types of a generic method parameters like this you should use this  T1,T2 notation.

Answer (score -1):

You could get around the whole issue by making your program simpler.  E.g. use a table of objects instead of generics in this case.

Comment: - That is not the answer to my question. The whole idea of generics is to provide type safety. With objects, you can store anything which is not the case with Generics. The type which you define only that can be stored in that particular object.